# Get cell number of the first empty column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get the first cell that is empty in a column but I don't have an idea how to accomplish that.
For example, I have this column

[image: Sheet example]

How can i get for example in A:7 that the first empty cell is 5 (i only get the number)

I tryied this, but is giving me a error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **A7** enter the *array formula:*

```
=MIN(IF(A1:A6="",ROW(A1:A6)))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

**EDIT#1:**

Here is the Google Sheet equivalent:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying it in google sheet but is always giving me a formula error

Comment: @Luis  Try using ***ARRAYFORMULA***

Comment: How? like this =ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF(A1:A6="",ROW(A1:A6)))) ? @Gary's Student

Comment: Is give error :/

Comment: @Luis  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Gary, just edit my question with a picture with the error. I think i have the save as you. Do i need to activate something?

Comment: @Luis  ***Check your regional settings.***

Comment: hmm, what that have to do with my regional settings? where do i change it?

Comment: Found it, i think it had to be a ; 
=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF(A1:A6=""; ROW(A1:A6))))

Comment: @Luis  Good Job !

Comment: But this only works if is a small number of rows. If i have 100 rows it always returng circular references.. :(

Comment: @Luis  If the formula is in the same column, it must be **below** the data and refer only to the data above it